# QT Application Crash when mouse is over a push button

Tags: c++, qt

I will try to cut the story short as much as I can.
I statically compiled QT 5.11.2 to be able to compile a single executable under windows following this guide:
https://retifrav.github.io/blog/2018/02/17/build-qt-statically/

After many trials, compiling and such I was able to get in "release" mode a `.exe` of around 15MB.

I compiled it using different MinGW versions with the option `"QTPLUGIN.imageformats = -"` in the `.pro` project to avoid `-ltiff` error.
This is strange as my Application has no image handling opss...

My application is a basic and simple push button (no event associated).

The issue I am facing now is that when the mouse moves over the button and it should turn from grey to light blue the Windows wheel spins for a second before the application crashes with `Segmentation fault`.

Using dynamic compiling it works well and no crashes.

After many tries I found out that at least another QT objects crashes in the same way which is `RadioBox`. `CheckBox` and `Tool Button` are handled correctly the mouse over event.

I tried to change crashing object properties copying from working objects but still crashes!

I am desperate! After the nightmare of static compiling I landed to this issues and no googling helped me so far.

Tested Compilers are:

```
MinGW 4.9.2 g++
MinGW 5.3 g++
MinGW 7.3 g++
```

I also tried to remove the Debugger just in case.

Any help?

I am moving from Rad Studio to QT for its known issues finding more troubles than solutions.

Comment: Did it work when you where dynamically linking it? (i.e. has it ever worked)? Have you run it in through the debugger to see where it crashes? Also - purely out of curiosity - why do you want it statically linked? - this will make it a pain commercially speaking (but if its not commercial then its probably ok)

Comment: re: I works beautifully when Dynamically compiled
re: debug in release mode with static build is a pain in the butt. It simply ends the application with SIGSEGV
re: Adverse to your assumption commercially speaking a single file is much more appreciated than a full setup with a bunch of tedious libraries and licensewise as long as you do not modify QT Open Source libraries there is no problem with the license policy.

I have to ADD to my previous topic that I also tried to compile and debug with MinGW 64 seh version. All compilers are throwing the same result :(

Comment: I went through a similar pain-in-the-arse static compilation to improve the deployment. But in the end (for both widows and linux) I found that it was too much of a pain. I got my project working, but when I wanted to update qt creator I had to statically compile it again etc... But its very much easier to grab the libraries - you are using windows so you could benefit from windeployqt: https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/windows-deployment.html which does most of the work for you. Instead of delivering a single file you just deliver a folder easy. Also this link is not the official link for...

Comment: ... statically compiling qt libs. I recall, successfully using this link: https://doc.qt.io/QtForDeviceCreation/qtee-static-linking.html - although it appears to have changed (been updated) since last time I used it...

Comment: Thank you for the link. I looked into it but unfortunately no link really helpful.

Any tip about configuration line??

`configure -release -static -static-runtime -no-pch -optimize-size -opengl desktop -platform win32-g++ -prefix "C:\Qt\QT_static" -skip webengine -nomake tools -nomake tests -nomake examples -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg`

Comment: The config line is basically just saying what to compile. It looks about right to me. Release is good for size - but you may want the debug for the first time for debugging. You probably don't want the tool, tests and examples - just takes longer. I also assume you don't need webengine? The prefix is basically where to put it. Are you using any particular plugins?

Comment: Hi, thank you for following up. My application is a simple Widget app with just one push button with no event associated with it. It is the most basic and minimal application that could cone into my mind as PoC. This is why I am very surprised that it fails. I recompiled a few for times but same result. What should I try next?

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this as an answer because its far too long for a comment...

I did a "from scratch" install of qt. I did this starting from the qt git hub repo. Once finished, I added it as a kit to my qtcreator and re-built some old GUI projects I had with push buttons. I then took the exe's (they where about 500mb because I used debug config) and ran them on a PC that has never seen Qt (a travel laptop) and the two programs I tested both ran fine with button presses and no crashes.

So, here is the list of instructions that I used (for windows 10), you can perhaps try this from the start to see if this helps:

### 1. Preparation

In no particular order:

- install strawberry perl (required during compilation). Note normal perl does not seem to work very well.

  - from here: http://strawberryperl.com/
- Get the qt source:

  - `git clone https://github.com/qt/qt5.git qt5`
  - `git checkout 5.12.1` (specific build instead of 5.12 latest)
  - `git submodule update --init --recursive`
  - `git submodule foreach --recursive "git clean -dfx" && git clean -dfx` (ensure repo is clean)
- Download and install mingw64 (32 bit) from: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/. I used options:

  - version    7.3.0
  - Arch       i686
  - Threads    posix
  - Exception  dwarf
  - Build-rev  0
- Windows 10 NTFS long path names

  - Get MediaCreationTool1809.exe from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10 and run it as admin.
  - https://superuser.com/questions/1119883/windows-10-enable-ntfs-long-paths-policy-option-missing

    - Once you installed step 1 (maybe reboot) then you should be able to do windows button "gpedit.msc" and see the open to open gpedit
    - Right click it, run as admin. Then: Local Computer Policy --> Computer Config --> Administrative Templates --> System --> FileSystem --> Enable Win32 Long Paths (double click)
    - In there click the enable tick box and ok.
- Install Python (required during make install):

  - From here: https://www.python.org/downloads/

**NOTE:** in the mingw folder there should be a mingw-xx.bat file to open an cmd prompt environment for gcc. Run this for all cmd prompts to do the following actions.

**NOTE:** make sure you edit the paths so that strawberry perl .../bin is before any other perl's
So the dos env setup should look like:

```
    set PATH=D:\install\StrawberryPerl\perl\bin;%PATH%
    set PATH=D:\install\mingw-w64\i686-7.3.0-posix-dwarf\mingw32\bin;%PATH%
    set PATH=D:\install\Qt\qt5\qtbase\bin;%PATH%
    set PATH=D:\install\Qt\qt5\gnuwin32\bin;%PATH%
```

Where `D:\install\Qt\qt5` is where my qt5 git repo is.

### 2. Configuration

#### 2.1. Static Config

- Create folder at the same level as `../qt5/` repo called `../qt5-static-build/` (for example) and cd into it, then run:

```
- ..\qt5\configure -debug -opensource -static -static-runtime -skip webengine -nomake examples -nomake tests -nomake tools -accessibility -no-sql-sqlite -no-opengl -platform win32-g++ -qt-zlib -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -confirm-license -prefix "C:\install\Qt\5.12.1-static"
```

#### 2.2. Shared Lib Config

- Create folder at the same level as `../qt5/` repo called `../qt5-build/` (for example) and cd into it, then run:

```
..\qt5\configure -debug -opensource -skip webengine -nomake examples -nomake tests -nomake tools -accessibility -no-sql-sqlite -no-opengl -platform win32-g++ -qt-zlib -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -confirm-license -prefix "C:\install\Qt\5.12.1-sharedlib"
```

### 3. Compile and installation

Either way you configured qt (static or not) this part is the same, basically run:

```
mingw32-make -j8
mingw32-make install -j8
```

**Note:** you can use whatever parallel number you want (`-j<num-jobs>`). Each stage takes a while depending on your CPU of course.

Once you have finished, the install path set in your config line (e.g. `C:\install\Qt\5.12.1-static`) will contain your qt install. You can then add this in qtcreator as a new qt version (if that is how you are building it).

### Appendix - release static configuration

You may want the following configuration if you want release builds etc (but I did not test this yet):

..\qt5\configure with the following options:

`-release -optimize-size -opengl desktop -no-pch -platform win32-g++ -opensource -static -static-runtime -skip webengine -nomake examples -nomake tests -nomake tools -accessibility -no-sql-sqlite -no-opengl -platform win32-g++ -qt-zlib -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -confirm-license -prefix "C:\install\Qt\5.12.1-static"`

where I added:

- `-release` - instead of debug
- `-optimize-size` - make smallest size
- `-opengl desktop` - opengl if you must have it
- `-no-pch` - no pre-compiled headers, not sure you need this, but...
- `-platform win32-g++` - Again, this may help if you have build issues, but probably don't need it.